# iOS webapp - how to keep full screen mode between pages

Tags: html, ios, web-applications

I am creating a tiny site and I would like to allow the users to save it as app from iOS devices. I have added this in each page:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

This seems to work fine as the main page is shown as full screen after the user saves it to the home screen, however as soon any click is linked the full screen is disabled and a top bar with a "Done" button on the top left of the corner appears.

I'd like that whatever the user does the page keep be visible as full screen.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by adding a manifest file:

1. create a manifest file in the root of your web app with a similar content to this:

```
    {
      "name": "My Super App",
      "short_name": "My App",
      "display": "standalone",
      "scope": "/my-app-path/",
      "start_url": "/my-app-path/"
    }
```

2. Add a link to the manifest file
3. Remove and add again the app to your home

Comment: You only need `"display": "standalone"` for this. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/display